# Uniformity in Accessing SDF and SQL Server Datasources

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

My application has the ability to run off an `.SDF` file (SQL Server Compact) for data if the client supports it, or a SQL Server database if the client does not support `.SDF` files. The only problem is in writing code that will funnel into a common track whether I'm dealing with one or the other. Let me give some examples of where I'm going with this.

I don't want to have to write conditional statements every time I need to do something to see if the database is linked to a server or if I'm accessing it from the `.SDF`, so I switched my syntax to (SQL to Linq). I have two of the .dbml files that map out the tables and fields so that I can now use the sql to linq syntax. My only problem is that if the two .dbml files exist in the same project they clash because there are public declarations on them. As far as I can tell, I can't exactly make these classes private or somehow separate them so that even though they have identical names and fields, they wont throw errors stating the class has multiple signatures.

```
Public Sub SDFAccess()
        Dim dc As New Members("Data Source = C:\Members.sdf")  

        Dim q = _
            From Leader In dc.GetTable(Of Roles)() _
            Select Leader

        DataGridView2.DataSource = q
 End Sub

 Public Sub ServerAccess()
        Dim dc As New ServerDBDataContext()

        Dim q = _
            From sLeader In dc.GetTable(Of ServerRole)() _
            Select sLeader

        DataGridView2.DataSource = q
    End Sub
```

I need to be able to just have one sub that runs for both conditions. Regardless of if the data is coming from a `.SDF` or a SQL Server database. I appreciate your time.

**Update-1**
So I've noticed in the `.DBML` Designer files overloads for New(). Is it possible I could use just one `.DBML` file for either server or Compact access as long as both data sources are identical?

**Update-2** 
I would also assume that if everything was the same the only thing that holds me back between the two `.DBML`is the System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name:="TestServer")> attribute in the Server `.DBML` file.

**Update-3**
Alright new approach, maybe... I can include both classes from the two seperate generated `.DBML` files and only use the properties I need then submit the context back to the datasource. Problem again is how do I force the program into ignoring a class  in the namespace and not writting a conditional everytime I want to perform some action. I'm beginning to wonder if I should just use a dataset as an intermediary. I really had my hopes on picking up Linq-Sql for this one though.

Comment: In regards to the "Public" class identifier problem I would like to change (of ServerRole) to (Of Roles) like the above but I get errors indicating Roles has multiple definitions because the .dbml file is a public class.

Comment: The only thing that separates the two from each other in the designer is a Database Attribute(Name:"DBName") and a table attribute. This has to be possible.

Comment: Apparently SQL-Linq is dieing... Time to move on.